# how to create by code an Excel workbook with several sheets using pandas.to_excel?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

with an SQL query, I get a number of customers, then a number of suppliers for each customer.
The objective is to create an Excel workbook per customer and in this workbook, at the rate of one sheet per supplier, copy the details of the supplier's invoices.
The code below allows you to create Excel workbooks and one sheet per supplier, but the copy of invoices per supplier does not work. Where is the error?
My code :

```
Clients=list(generator_df['Client'].unique())
for i in range(0,len(Clients)):
if len(Clients[i])!= 0:
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path+'"'+Clients[i]+".xlsx")
Four = generator_df[['Four']][generator_df['Client'] == Clients[i]].dropna()
Fournisseurs = list(Four['Four'].unique())
        
for j in range(0,len(Fournisseurs)):
if j == 0:
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(Fournisseurs[0])
Detail = detail_df[['Num_facture','Date_facture','Code_produit','Designation','Qte','PU_net','Montant_HT']][(detail_df['Fournisseur'] == Fournisseurs[0]) & (detail_df['Client']==Clients[i])].dropna()
Detail.to_excel(path+'"'+Clients[i]+".xlsx", sheet_name = Fournisseurs[0], header = True, index = False)
                
else:
Num=str(j)
worksheetNum = workbook.add_worksheet(Fournisseurs[j])
Detail_j = detail_df[['Num_facture','Date_facture','Code_produit','Designation','Qte','PU_net','Montant_HT']][(detail_df['Fournisseur'] == Fournisseurs[j]) & (detail_df['Client'] == Clients[i])].dropna()
Detail_1.to_excel(path+'"'+Clients[i]+".xlsx", sheet_name = Fournisseurs[j], header = True, index = False)    
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Please correct your code indentation and format, so we can help you

Comment: Can this [example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html) help?

Comment: after several modifications of the code, the problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

after several modifications of the code, the problem is solved.
"

```py
Clients = list(generator_df['Client'].unique())
for i in range(0, len(Clients)):
    if len(Clients[i]) != 0:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
            path+'"'+Clients[i]+".xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
        Four = generator_df[['Four']][generator_df['Client']
                                      == Clients[i]].dropna()
        Fournisseurs = list(Four['Four'].unique())
        for j in range(0, len(Fournisseurs)):
        if j == 0:
        Detail = detail_df[['Num_facture', 'Date_facture', 'Code_produit',
                            'Designation', 'Qte', 'PU_net', 'Montant_HT']][(detail_df['Fournisseur']
                                                                            == Fournisseurs[0]) & (detail_df['Client'] == Clients[i])].dropna()
        Detail.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=Fournisseurs[0],
                        header=True, index=False)
        else:
            Num = str(j)
            Detail_j = detail_df[['Num_facture', 'Date_facture', 'Code_produit',
                                  'Designation', 'Qte', 'PU_net', 'Montant_HT']][(detail_df['Fournisseur'] == Fournisseurs[j]) & (detail_df['Client'] ==
                                                                                                                                  Clients[i])].dropna()
            Detail_j.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=Fournisseurs[j],
                              header=True, index=False)
            writer.save()
```

Comment: Please correct your code indentation and format, see: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Ok, I did my best attempt to format your code, Can you, please, verify if that is correct, and use [edit] to correct it?

Comment: Hmmz [pylance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-pylance-fast-feature-rich-language-support-for-python-in-visual-studio-code/) failed on some lines.....   